# starting a new view after string array finishes

Tags: android, android-widget

So, I have this "next" button which calls a string array and when count reaches "-1" I would like to start a new view. How can I do this?

```
    Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
     nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
            if (count < myString.length) {
                 lessonsDialog.setText(myString[count]);
                 count++;
             } else {
                 if (count < myString.length  [-1]) {
                     handler2.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MESSAGE_SHOW_POPUP2, TIME_DELAY2);
                 }
             }
         }
     });
```

Comment: What do you mean "start" a new view? Views don't get started, they get inflated.

Comment: Sorry, yeah thats what I meant. the bit im stuck on is how to code the "if the string array count finishes then on the next click of that button, inflate a new view"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нou can call removeView(View child); and addView(View child); on ViewGroup.

Example

```
LinearLayout viewHolder = (Linearlayout) findViewById(R.id.view_holder);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View viewBeforeClick = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_VIEW_ID1, null, false);
View viewAfterClick = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_VIEW_ID2, null, false);

viewHolder.addView(viewBeforeClick);

//when clicked on next button

viewHolder.removeView(viewBeforeClick);
viewHolder.addView(viewAfterClick);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How can I make it work with this.         else {
                 if (count < myString.length  [-1])

Comment: if (myString[count - 1] != null) got it going.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283164/deflate-view-and-inflate-another

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to start new activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourClassName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i wanted to keep the same background and have a new layout inflate instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View viewName = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_VIEW_ID, null, false);
```

Use method addView(View child) and removeView(View view) to add and remove views.

Comment: I think I might of explained it badly. I got the inflate bit going...just cant figure out how to trigger it with my "next button".

Comment: the next button runs a string array and after three or four clicks on the next button when all the items finish displaying and the user presses the next button again, I am trying to get it to inflate a new view...is this possible?

Comment: else { if (count < myString.length  [-1])